# Skip back stack items on jetpack compose navigation

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm having an issue with jetpack compose navigation back stack handling:

Lets say I have four screens in jetpack compose

```
ScreenA
ScreenB
ScreenC
ScreenD
```

I can navigate from:

```
ScreenA -> ScreenB
ScreenB -> ScreenC
ScreenC -> ScreenD
//Here is the tricky part
ScreenD -> ScreenB
```

I want to make sure that when I navigate from ScreenD to ScreenB there is only ScreenA in the back stack.
I don't want to have to do

```
navController.popBackStack()
navController.popBackStack()
```

I have tried several combinations of

```
navController.navigate([ScreenA.route/ScreenB.route]) {
    popUpTo([ScreenA.route/ScreenB.route]) {
        inclusive = true
    }
}
```

But when pressing the back button I go back to `ScreenD` which isn't expected

How can I correctly navigate back here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove ScreenC from the backstack before navigating to ScreenD, because when you call  `navigate()` function it adds your current destination to the backstack by default.

Try this in your ScreenC :

```
navController.navigate(ScreenD.route) {
    popUpTo(ScreenC.route) { inclusive = true }
}
```

Google docs [Navigate to a composable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-to-composable)